# How to print code, type of PostgreSQL / plpgsql exception

Tags: postgresql, exception, error-handling

Given this pl/pgSQL function

```
drop function if exists f( float );
create function f( x float )
  returns float
  language plpgsql
  as $$
    begin
      return 1 / x;
    exception
      when others then
        raise notice 'oops';
        return 0::float;
    end;
  $$;
```

it is clear that `select f( 0 );` will result in an code 22012 exception, type `division_by_zero`. Knowing this I can narrow down the selector of the `exception` clause to `when division_by_zero then ...`.

However, for arbitrary functions, how can I obtain the error type? Is there anything like, say, `raise notice error.code`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sqlstate`, example:

```
drop function if exists f( float );
create function f( x float )
  returns float
  language plpgsql
  as $$
    begin
      return 1 / x;
    exception
      when others then
        raise notice 'oops %', sqlstate;
        return 0::float;
    end;
$$;

select f(0);

NOTICE:  oops 22012
 f 
---
 0
(1 row)
```

Read more about [Errors and Messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) and [Trapping Errors.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)